# as.POSIXct rejects +1300 timezone

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

I'm using `as.POSIXct` to parse times with timezones, like this:

```
as.POSIXct("2009-01-05 14:19 +1200", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z")
```

However, if the string includes the timezone information `+1300`, the function returns `NA`:

```
> as.POSIXct("2009-01-05 14:19 +1300", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z")
[1] NA
```

Aparently `+1300` is a valid timezone ([NZDT – New Zealand Daylight Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/antarctica/nzdt.html)). How to convince R to parse it?

Comment: R usually passes most of its POSIX processing to the OS libraries, I think, so you may have to do some hand-parsing here, strip the +1300, and pass `tz="NZDT"` explicitly ...

Comment: I think that might be a bug, and worth reporting.

Comment: @hadley, I've just reported it as a bug at https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15768

Comment: This [bug](http://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15768) was fixed in R 3.1.0 patched ([NEWS](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2014/04/24#n2014-04-24))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15768) in 3.0.2 release, which was [fixed](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2014/04/24#n2014-04-24) in [R-3.1.0 Patched](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html) build.