# strptime() rejects +1300 time-zone offset on Windows

Tags: r, posixct, strptime

I'm using `R 3.4.0` on Windows 7.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

When I am using `strptime`/`as.POSIXct` with a `%z` offset that is larger than `+1200` the return is `NA`:

```
> strptime("2017-02-02 13:00:00 +1300", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
[1] NA
> as.POSIXct("2017-02-02 13:00:00 +1300", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
[1] NA
```

This has been asked before ([as.POSIXct rejects +1300 timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182569/as-posixct-rejects-1300-timezone)) and the bug was supposedly fixed in R 3.1.0.

I wonder whether anybody else still has the same issue and whether it might be Windows specific? I tested this in different `R` version from `3.3.1` to `3.4.1` on Windows 7, 8, and 10 and got the same return.

The usual way without `%z` but with the correct timezone `tz` works:

```
> strptime("2017-02-02 13:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "NZ")
[1] "2017-02-02 13:00:00 NZDT"
```

Comment: I agree, and it is windows-only (your command works on R-3.3.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). And to paraphrase a comment in your linked question: "it is a (windows-specific) bug, and [worth reporting](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi)".

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Bugzilla is closed to new members, so I have to figure out how to report this.